# Laravel Homestead gives 502 Bad Gateway error instead of laravel error page

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I've noticed an interesting behavior on laravel homestead.

The specifications:

Laravel 4.2

nginx/1.8.0

PHP 5.6.9-1+deb.sury.org~utopic+2 (fpm-fcgi) (built: May 24 2015 16:16:14)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
    with blackfire v0.23.3, https://blackfire.io/, by SensioLabs

on `model.blade.php` page 502 Bad Gateway error with undefined variable:

```
var_dump($publicationsss);
```

Works fine with defined variable:

```
var_dump($publications);
```

I want to see a laravel error page instead of nginx error message. What should i do ?

Error Log Message:

> 2015/05/30 21:27:23 [error] 20048#0: *307 recv() failed (104:
>   Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream,
>   client: 192.168.10.1, server: api.weakapi.dev, request: "GET
>   /panel/banner/edit/link/16 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "api.weakapi.dev"

Comment: Have you ever resolved this error?

Comment: yes by making a clean install from the scratch

Comment: For others who are facing this problem, if you are running php 7.3, remove xdebug, it's a bug with php7.3 and xdebug

Comment: @MohammadKawsara could you elaborate a bit more, please? I'm facing a similar issue with PHP 7.3.3 and removing xdebug didn't solve it

Comment: @FelipeFrancisco I'm really sorry it's been a while, besides I'm sure it was all about removing xdebug, please restart your machine or services

Comment: as @MoKawsara suggested, it is related to x-debug. For anyone having the same issue, simply comment the zend_extension=xdebug.so line of the xdebug.ini file of each php version of your homestead box. 

How to link: https://christattum.com/disabling-xdebug-in-laravel-homestead/